# User.ReadBasic.All Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a application that uses the microsoft graph api, but for some reason when I add a new permission, in this case User.ReadBasic.All, its not present in the token.

[image: Image no.1]

[image: Image no.2]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User needs to agree to the new permission. You may need to raise the consent prompt again. Only after that it will appear in the token, and only in a new token of course :)

Comment: Added the prompt for the user to agree, now it works like a charm. Thanks :D